# Why are there so few Force sensitive Mandalorians?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, mandalorian

I noticed that there aren't many Mandalorian Force users. Is there something wrong with their genes or is it that the *Star Wars* creators just don't want Force sensitive Mandalorians? I know only a few noteworthy Mandalorian Force users, one of whom is Tarre Vizsla.

Comment: From what I can see (uneducated guess) there are very few force sensitive individuals in every species in the Star Wars universe; so that reflect in the number of Force sensitive Mandalorians

Comment: It depends on whether you are looking for an answer from Canon or Legends. In Legends the Mandalorians used to be a single race called the Taung, until eventually they starting letting in any species that wanted to join them and believed in their culture, hence they weren't really a single ethnicity/race after a certain point. The Taung weren't known to be Force-sensitive, but if you're asking why none of the humans who are part of the Mandalorians seem to be Force-sensitive, that probably gets into a very different discussion about Mandalorian culture/history.

Comment: In my limited knowledge of the Star Wars universe and lore, isn't the Force sensitivity determined by the number of midi-chlorians in the body of the subject? 
Maybe Mandalorians aren't ideal hosts for midi-chlorians, or there's some reason related to their lower count of midi-chlorians.

Comment: @Phyneas it was similar with Legends origin of the Sith. Originally the "Sith" was a single species, somewhat strong in the Dark Side. They joined together (both politically and conjugally) with fallen Jedi to form what became the Sith Order.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Mandalorians are not a species but it is more of a philosophy. Anybody having this philosophy can join the Mandalorians.
- Mandalorians are not part of the Republic, they've even fought quite often against the Jedi. Jedi can therefore not test Mandalorians for Force-sensitivity. People may therefore be Force-sensitive without knowing it.

From the Wookieepedia [article on Mandalorians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalorian):

> Mandalorians were a **predominantly** human ethnolinguistic cultural group who originated on the planet Mandalore. Mandalorians had a particularly unique role in galactic history as **legendary warriors against the Jedi**, and could be commonly found not only on the Mandalorian homeworld and its moon, Concordia, but across Mandalorian Space and the galaxy at large on worlds such as Kalevala, Krownest, and Concord Dawn. Mandalore had a largely martial history, but by the time of the Clone Wars the pacifist and reformist New Mandalorian political faction controlled Mandalore's government, led by Duchess Satine Kryze. This led to internal conflict with other Mandalorian groups like Death Watch, who wanted to maintain the warrior ways of their Mandalorian heritage.
>
> ...
>
> Their first confrontations with the Jedi Knights took the Mandalorians by surprise: their use of the Force and the powers it granted them was a challenge that they had never seen before. However, the prideful nature of the Mandalorians would not allow that disadvantage to stand, and the technologically advanced people began to devise ways to overcome the powers of the enigmatic Jedi. The result was a major advancement in the development of Mandalorian technology, specifically of their arsenal and their infamous armor. They also developed a fighting style that combined their entire arsenal and skills to allow them to counteract the Jedi's supernatural abilities. With these new technologies, the Mandalorians began to win their share of conflicts with the Jedi, and their warriors earned the reputation of being capable of confronting and defeating Jedi Knights.

It is not that Mandalorians are less Force-sensitive than other races but they are not tested. It is the same with the Outer Rim. You won't find a lot of Jedi being from there as they are not part of the Republic. In *The Phantom Menace*, they mention that Anakin would've been found earlier if he was born in the Republic. It's the same with Mandalorians.

Comment: I understand the jedi's limitation because they are not part of republic but what about the sith?

Comment: There are two Siths, a teacher and a student. It is probably more likely that a Mandalorian is discovered early enough by a Jedi to train them than by the Sith needing a student.

Comment: Rule of the two didn't exist during old republic era.

Comment: @faust If the Mandalorians are rarely tested because they are against the Jedi, would they really see the Sith as any different?  *"Jedi, Sith, whatever...  You carry a lightsaber, use your fancy Force, and tell us what to do.  We are Mandalorians, so get lost."*

Answer (score 0):

if I remember right didn't the Jedi used to take the Mandalorian children who were Force sensitive and they stopped it because the people started saying they were stealing their children.

Comment: If you could remember where this info came from please [edit] it into your answer